# Modify function/variable values of the plugin via vim config

Tags: vim

I use https://github.com/pbogut/fzf-mru.vim plugin which writes information in:

```
/Users/karl/.cache/fzf_mru/cache.txt
```

but I would like to set my own path to the file. As far as I understood by default there is no such possibility, so I'm looking for a way to do it via vim config, i.e. without changing plugin itself.

This plugin basically consists of 3 files and in:

```
https://github.com/pbogut/fzf-mru.vim/blob/master/autoload/fzf_mru/mrufiles.vim
```

we can see that there is a function `fzf_mru#mrufiles#cachefile()` which points to the necessary file. `:echo fzf_mru#mrufiles#cachefile()` also points to:

```
/Users/karl/.cache/fzf_mru/cache.txt
```

and if I understand correctly then I need to change the value of variables of this function. Something like `let g:cafile='/a/b/file.txt'` in the config.

But all my attempts were unsuccessful, apparently I do not quite understand how to do it. Maybe someone can give me a hint. Maybe it is not possible to do this at all without modifying the plugin itself?

Answer (score 0):

`s:cache_dir` is a script-local variable that can't be overridden with a global one so you can't change the behaviour of the functions from the outside. This means that the code must be changed to allow user customisation.

You have two options:

1. do it yourself… and send a PR,
2. open an issue and let the maintainer do it.

If you choose option #1, you will have to change [that function](https://github.com/pbogut/fzf-mru.vim/blob/master/autoload/fzf_mru/utils.vim#L17):

```
fu! fzf_mru#utils#opts()
  let s:lash = fzf_mru#utils#lash()
  let usrhome = $HOME . s:lash( $HOME )
  let cahome = exists('$XDG_CACHE_HOME') ? $XDG_CACHE_HOME : usrhome.'.cache'
  let cadir = cahome.s:lash(cahome).'fzf_mru'
  let s:cache_dir = cadir
endf
```

to something like:

```
fu! fzf_mru#utils#opts()
  let s:lash = fzf_mru#utils#lash()
  if exists('g:fzf_mru_cache_dir')
    let s:cache_dir = g:fzf_mru_cache_dir
  else
    let usrhome = $HOME . s:lash( $HOME )
    let cahome = exists('$XDG_CACHE_HOME') ? $XDG_CACHE_HOME : usrhome.'.cache'
    let cadir = cahome.s:lash(cahome).'fzf_mru'
    let s:cache_dir = cadir
  endif
endf
```

which should allow you to define your cache directory in your `vimrc`:

```
let g:fzf_mru_cache_dir = '$HOME/foo/bar'
```